# React Native navigation - navigation.navigate is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I try to make my application and using the React's navigation and when I try to make a button no change my screen like this : `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Connect')` and when I click on my button I have this error : `navigation.navigate is not a function (in 'navigation.navigate('Connect'), 'navigation.navigate is undefined'`

However I used the same button on my Home screen and it's works ! maybe my props navigation is not ready on my other screen 'Congratulations' ?

my code :

Congratulations.js -

```
export default function Congratulations({navigation}, props) {

return (
    <View style={styles.isSubmit}>
        <Logo width={300} height={100} />
        <Text style={styles.congratulations}>Félicitations {props.firstName + ' ' + props.lastName}, tu peux désormais organiser tes évènements sur l'application ! </Text>
        <View style={{marginTop:30}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.buttonShadowConnect}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Connect')}>
                    <LinearGradient style={styles.button} colors={['#FD867E', '#FD7EAC']} start={[0, 0.65]}
                                    end={[0.70, 1]}>
                        <Text style={styles.textButton}>Connexion</Text>
                    </LinearGradient>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
); }
```

my Navigation.js :

```
 <NavigationContainer theme={Theme}>
            <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" drawerType={"slide"} options={options}>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ title: "Accueil" }}/>
                <Drawer.Screen name="JoinUs" component={JoinUs} options={{ title: "Nous rejoindre" }}/>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Connect" component={Connect} options={{ title: "Se connecter" }}/>
            </Drawer.Navigator>

        </NavigationContainer>
```

and I call my component Congratulations in my Component JoinUsForm.js like this :

```
    <Congratulations firstName={getFirstName} lastName={getLastName} navigation={navigation}></Congratulations>
```

you can check on my repo if you want : https://github.com/teddyboirin/myparty
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've run your project on expo without issue.
I think you forgot to run pod install on the iOS folder:

```
cd ios && pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

The destructuring Props was the reason of my problem ! thanks !